# ¿Por qué mi función funciona y luego desaperece cuando uso "<form>"?

Tags: javascript, html

No sabía muy bien como describir el problema, pero así es. Estoy recién aprendiendo y imagino que será una obviedad pero no logro encontrar ninguna solución...

Estoy haciendo una página en la que escribes un mensaje en un input, le das al botón, y aparece el mismo mensaje abajo:

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="sub-container">
            <h2>Escribe un mensaje que te gustaría dejar</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese mensaje" name="" id="unicoinput">
                <button id="enviarmensaje" type="submit" >Enviar</button>
            <h2>Ultimo mensaje recibido:</h2>
            <h3 id="loadmessage"></h3> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
var boton = document.getElementById('enviarmensaje');
boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //console.log("probando")
    document.body.style.background = "blue";
})
```

Resulta que si pongo exactmente lo mismo pero añado form entre input y button:

```html
<form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese mensaje" name="" id="unicoinput">
                <button id="enviarmensaje" type="submit" >Enviar</button>
            </form>
```

Pues entonces el código de cambiar el fondo a azul (o el console.log) se ejecuta, pero luego se anula. Es decir, durante un segundo el fondo se pone azul, pero luego vuelve a normal. Lo mismo para el mensaje "probando". Aparece durante medio segundo y luego desaperece de la consola de Javascript.

Como hacer que funcione bien con el form?

Comment: Hola, cambia el atributo `type="submit"` por `type="button"` al botón que tienes en tu HTML

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que entender que lo que hace el `submit` es enviar tu `form` al servidor (con los datos que haya recogido) por eso "desaparecen" los elementos de tu navegador cuando haces click en el botón (estarías haciendo un envío a servidor).

Como te han comentado, si cambias el tipo del botón enviar de `submit` a `button` no se realiza el envío a servidor:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById('enviarmensaje');
boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //console.log("probando")
    document.body.style.background = "blue";
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="sub-container">
          <h2>Escribe un mensaje que te gustaría dejar</h2>
              <input type="text" placeholder="ingrese mensaje" name="" id="unicoinput">
              <button id="enviarmensaje" type="button" >Enviar</button>
          <h2>Ultimo mensaje recibido:</h2>
          <h3 id="loadmessage"></h3> 
      </div>
  </div>
```

Te recomiendo estas dos lecturas:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp